# Using Previous/Next buttons in remote pages for tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a series of tabs that are displaying content from a remote source. The end result will be a series of forms in each tab that when the user fills out and clicks the button will take them to the next tab. Only the tab with focus will be enabled and all the other tabs will be disabled. I have the basic function for all of this to occur - however, I am having trouble with the previous and next buttons working with the remote HTML pages. I have a Fiddle setup with the basic controls working - but without the remote page calls.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k4Hua/1/)

HTML for parent page:

```
 <div id="tabs">
  <ul>
            <li><a href="#tabs-1">General Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-2">Phone Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-3">Emergency Contact Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-4">Job Related Information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tabs-5">Miscellaneous Information</a></li>
  </ul>


<div id="tab-content">
        <div id="tabs-1">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-2">
        </div>
        <div id="tabs-3">
        </div> 
        <div id="tabs-4">
        </div>        
        <div id="tabs-5">
        </div>  
 </div>
```

Tab Script: This is how I load the data

```
<script>
    $('#tabs-1').load('nes/data/EmployeeGenInfo.htm');
    $('#tabs-2').load('nes/data/EmployeePhoneInfo.htm');
    $('#tabs-3').load('nes/data/EmployeeEmergInfo.htm');
    $('#tabs-4').load('nes/data/EmployeeJobInfo.htm');
    $('#tabs-5').load('nes/data/EmployeeMiscInfo.htm');
</script>
```

This is PART TWO:

I need to GET data from a SERVLET and have that data populate the child page in the tabs for each form. Thus far I have the correct functions working for the tabs - you can see a quasi working example here - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5V5um/14/) - the tab content can't be shown since it is being called remotely. Here is the JAVASCRIPT for the TAB controls:

```
$(function() {

    $("#tabs").tabs({disabled: [0,1,2,3,4,5]});

    var $emptabs = $('#tabs').tabs();

    $('#tabs').on('click', '#submit1', function() {
        var selected = $emptabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", []);
        $emptabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", [0,2,3,4,5]);
    });

    $('#tabs').on('click', '#submit2', function() {
        var selected = $emptabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", []);
        $emptabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", [0,1,3,4,5]);
    });

    $('#tabs').on('click', '#submit3', function() {
        var selected = $emptabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", []);
        $emptabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", [0,1,2,4,5]);
    });

    $('#tabs').on('click', '#submit4', function() {
        var selected = $emptabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", []);
        $emptabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", [0,1,2,3,5]);
    });

    $('#tabs').on('click', '#submit5', function() {
        var selected = $emptabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", []);
        $emptabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", [0,1,2,3,4]);
    });

        $('#tabs').on('click', '#reset', function() {
        var selected = $emptabs.tabs('option', 'selected');
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", []);
        $emptabs.tabs('select', selected-5);
        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", [0,1,2,3,4,5]);
    });

});
```

All the HTML is still the same. I need to know how and where to put my AJAX calls for each button. I know it's going to look something like this:

```
var v = $("#form1").validate({
        submitHandler: function() { 
             $.ajax({
                        type:"post",
                        url:"ActionServlet",
                        data:'JSON',
                        success: function(response){
                            alert("FORM SHOULD SUBMIT HERE");
                        // Change only the header of the file.
                    if (v2.form()) {
                        $emptabs.tabs('select', selected+1);
                        $emptabs.tabs("option", "disabled", [0,2,3,4,5]);
                        }
                    }
            });
```

I already have a SERVLET setup from a previous project that used Accordions instead of tabs, so I know the process is pretty much the same. But the Accordions are set up much differently than the tabs. Let me know if you need to see anything else.

Comment: Everything seems to be working OK... what is the problem in relation to what you have on the jsFiddle?

Comment: I am trying to get the next buttons to work in a remote HTML file, as explained above. I can't put the buttons in the tab content DIV in the parent page, as they won't show up because the remote page call overrides whatever is in that DIV. I need the buttons in the remote HTML file to control the tabs in the parent page. I simply provided the JSFiddle as a starting point to finding a solution because that's just where I'm at with it and stuck there.

Comment: How are you inserting the remote HTML into the page? Are you using ajax to copy the content from the remote page into the current one, or are you using iframes?

Comment: I'll edit my first post with the HTML for the parent page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem could be that your buttons don't exist in the DOM when you define the click() functions.

Try delegating the click events:

```
$('#myTabs').on('click', '#finish1', function() {
    etc.
```

This allows the buttons to be added after the DOM is initially loaded.

Comment: BINGO! give that man a prize! ;) Works like a charm, but i'm sure you knew it would. ;) I'm more of a designer who is just learning how to put all this JQuery business together, so I really appreciate your help. Now, on to the next phase, which is submitting each form via JSP/AJAX - something else I'm learning in a most frustrating way ;)

Comment: Glad I could help. I was in the same boat not too long ago! Could you accept the answer if it worked for you?

Comment: I'd like to add a part two to this situation instead of creating a whole new question, since this is the code that will be modified for the second part of the process. Or should I just create a whole new question and just refer back to this one for the first part?

Comment: If you have permissions sufficient enough to edit your first post, add the new info underneath what you've got so far (as long as the second part relates directly to your first question; otherwise, create a new one)